# ERC1155 wrapper to ERC721

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft

I have seen a couple of wrappers/adapters from ERC1155 to ERC20 but no from ERC1155 to ERC721: https://github.com/gnosis/1155-to-20

Does anyone know any public implementation?

I'm thinking to implement a wrapper for 1155 to 721, or thinking if will be possible to implement a token that implement both interfaces, 1155 and 721.